# Jenkins Pipeline config error while trying to docker pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have the following lines of code in my jenkins pipeline config .

```
     docker login -u axhdhcololjk/jenkins -p $OCI_AUTH_TOKEN  jed.ocir.io '''
```

I want to rewrite the same code using `docker.withRegistry` function from `docker pipeline` jenkins plugin.  I tried the following

```
          docker.withRegistry("${DOCKER_REGISTRY}", "${OCI_AUTH_TOKEN}")
```

but the authentication is failing with below error

```
     ERROR: Could not find credentials matching
```

Can somebody please help to rewrite the same code. I think it is failing because the user is not defined in the function but how to pass this parameter ?

https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/pipelines/docker-workflow

Answer (score 0):

Instead writing a groovy scripting code for Docker login use plug-in option in Jenkins.
In credentials add Docker username and password
Use global credentials option.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Karan but it required more detailed steps to be described:

1. check if credentials plugin were installed
2. add proper credentials type (username and password or auth token)
3. add credentials into your Jenkinsfile

   environment {

   ```
   DOCKER_CREDS=credentials('YOUR_DOCKER_CREDS')
   ```

   }
4. if you use username and password creds you can call username and password as follow:

   DOCKER_CREDS_USR - variable containing username

   DOCKER_CREDS_PSW - variable containing password